# In Python, assigning value -1 to an array from mat file results in 255

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, assign, mat

When I print the following array, all the values are 255 instead of -1. Any ideas? I guess it has something to do with 8 bits, but I can't understand it. I want to assign the -1 value to all the values in the array. I know there are workarounds like creating a new array with same size, I don't want that, I want to understand the problem.

```
dados = scipy.io.loadmat('myDataset.mat')
ds_Y_Test = dados['Y']

for value in ds_Y_Test:
    value[0]=-1
```

Comment: -1 in two's complement binary is `11111111`, which is 255 in unsigned binary, so that seems like a good guess!

Comment: You're right, but how can I assign it -1 instead, then? 

Should I change my question to be more clear that I want to do that?

Comment: How exactly do you print matrix? Is it a special scipy function? And I wonder exactly what type those values are. Is it standart python int or some custom scipy class for number representation?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what 'value' is? what is its type?

Comment: It seems you've loaded as `uint` - you will have to convert the array (e.g. with [`.astype`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html)).

Comment: I print the matrix like this:

`print ds_Y_Test_aux`

and the result is:

`[[255]
 [255]
 [255]
 ..., 
 [255]
 [255]
 [255]]`

Comment: @jonrsharpe you're right, how can I accept your answer? Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-1 in two's complement binary is 11111111, which is 255 in unsigned binary, so that seems like a good guess! It looks like you've loaded as the data as `uint8` - you will have to convert the array (e.g. with [.astype](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html)).